# How to change type of CtTypedElement

Tags: java, generics, inria-spoon

I am trying to write method to change type of typed element. I have CtLocalVariable `localVar` which I need to change.

My method is:

```
private void changeType(CtTypedElement<?> typedElem) {
    CtTypeReference<?> type = typedElem.getType();
    Optional<Class<?>> substituteOpt = TypeMapping.getSubstituteClass(type.getActualClass());

    substituteOpt.ifPresent(clazz -> {
        final CtTypeReference<?> newType = getFactory().Code().createCtTypeReference(clazz);
        typedElem.setType(newType);
    });
}
```

Line `TypeMapping.getSubstituteClass(type.getActualClass());` just returns substitute type for current type of local variable. Of course `typedElem.setType(newType);` has compile error.

Then I tried this and it also gave compile error:

```
CtTypeReference<?> type = typedElem.getType();
typedElem.setType(type);
```

Now I don't know is this the right path or should i try to change the declaration of local variable and change the whole local variable and not just type of existing.

The only example that compiles is:

```
private <T> void changeType(CtTypedElement<T> typedElem) {
    CtTypeReference<T> type = typedElem.getType();
    typedElem.setType(type);
    Optional<Class<?>> substituteOpt = TypeMapping.getSubstituteClass(type.getActualClass());

    substituteOpt.ifPresent(clazz -> {
        final CtTypeReference<T> newType = getFactory().Code().createCtTypeReference(clazz);
        typedElem.setType(newType);
    });
}
```

but that seams semantically incorrect to me because those are two different types (`type` and `newType`).

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand the issue there, but it seems weird that `CtTypeReference<?> type = typedElem.getType();
typedElem.setType(type);` gave compile error. Could you give us the compile error you got? Even better, if you manage to reproduce your errors in a unit test and push it in a PR on Github it could really help!

Comment: I have created PR with this compile error in spoon repo. I hope it will help.